# Unexpected Result in Intel 8080 Test ROM TST8080.ASM

Tags: testing, emulation, rom, intel-8080

I am creating an Intel 8080 and was running a test ROM named TST8080.ASM that I found at this Webiste. I am failing when this block of code runs:

```
CPOI:   RPE     ;TEST "RPE"

    ADI 010H    ;A=99H,C=0,P=0,S=1,Z=0

    CPE CPEI    ;TEST "CPE"

    ADI 002H    ;A=D9H,C=0,P=0,S=1,Z=0

    RPO     ;TEST "RPO"

    CALL    CPUER
```

I just don't understand why on the ADI instruction the parity flag is not set. When converting 99H to binary I get 10011001 which is an even number of bits yet the tests seems to expect the parity flag to not be set. If anyone could shed some light I would be grateful... Thx

I have read the Intel 8080 Manual which states "Byte "parity" is checked after certain operations. The number of 1 bits in a byte are counted, and if the total is odd, "odd" parity is flagged; if the total is even, "even" parity is flagged. The Parity bit is set to 1 for even parity, and is reset to 0 for add parity.

Comment: what makes you think A contains 99h?

Comment: @pm100 The A (accumulator) holds the result of the operation. When I run the test on my emulator the A register holds the value shown here which is 99h. I'm getting the same value as the tests just not the same flags.

Comment: @LuisColorado mistakenly did that.

Comment: @NoahLewis, I've did it for you, but editing your question you have a place to edit the tags you have used (this attracts unrelated/uninterested people to read your question, and can generate complaints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this online 8080 emulator](https://eliben.org/js8080/)

Enter the code:

```
mvi a, 89h
adi 10h
```

Press `step` and observe that the parity bit is set:
[image: screenshot of online 8080 emulator]